# Firefox : (firefox:12729): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

While running firefox, shows following error :

```
(firefox:12729): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed
```

OS: Ubuntu 14.04
FF : Quantun 57.0
ldd version: 2.19

I have updated glid. But same issue is there

Issue: Actually it shows issue while running Geckodriver in selenium

Can anyone please help me solving this issue.

Code to launch driver {if(BrowserCode.equalsIgnoreCase("FF")) { System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/AllDrivers/geckodriver"); DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.firefox(); capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true); WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities); driver.get("toolsqa.com"); } }

Regards
Vishal

Comment: Can you please write a context about your problem? Is it happening before your Selenium Tests open the browser or when you try to find an element? What language are you using? Can you provide some code, so people can try to help you?

Comment: Hi. Actually selenium launches the browser. And then shows above error. URL s not placed into browser. I am using java oracle 8 on ubuntu with selenium webdriver 3.8.1. FF version is Firefoz quantum 57.0

Comment: Code to launch driver {if(BrowserCode.equalsIgnoreCase("FF"))
   { 
    
    
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/AllDrivers/geckodriver");
     
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
    driver.get("http://www.toolsqa.com");
           
   }
   }

Comment: Please add the code in the question, instead of a comment. It makes it easier for all readers. What version of Geckodriver are you using? Also, have you tried to use Geckodiver accessing it in your path?